# Can totality be defined in terms of left-totality (or right-totality)?

Tags: terminology, relations

In the context of relations, can totality be defined in terms of left-totality (or right-totality)?

I ask this because both properties have the word "totality" in their names and one may think that there is a logical connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

Totality can't be defined in terms of left-totality and right-totality. Even if a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is both left-total and right-total it might not be total.

Example: $A = \{1,2\}$ and $R=\{(1,2),\;(2,1)\}$.

$R$ is left-total and right-total. But it is not total since $(1,1)\notin R$.

Totality implies both left-totality and right-totality because in a total relation, any $x,y$ in the set are related. One could argue either way whether or not this relationship is impled by the similar naming. Although the connotation of "total" in each case is similar, I don't think it's strong enough to read too much into it.

Definitions for these terms are within these links: [Special types of binary relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) and [Relations over a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Relations_over_a_set).

Comment: Is there any connection between them (for instance one being a stronger/weaker condition than the other) or it just happens that they have similar names?

Comment: @Loax I added to my answer in response to your comment.